# Why is $x a undefined variable for switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

It is display $x as undefined. What is wrong with my switch statement?

```
http://localhost/add.php?price_error=1

switch(isset($_GET['price_error']) && $_GET['price_error'] == $x){

            case 1:
                echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount price cannot be greater than original price</span><br/>';
                break;

            case 2:
                echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount cannot be less than 30% of original price</span><br/>';
                break;

            case 3:
                echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount price and original price cannot be greater than $30000 HKD</span><br/>';
                break;

            default: 
                false;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what it says on the tin: `$x` is undefined. I don't see that variable anywhere else other than your switch statement...

Comment: Where have you defined `$x` in your code above this point?

Comment: Since you don't show us where `$x` is defined (if it is at all), this is impossible to answer. Also, why are you passing a condition (i.e. boolean) to `switch()` rather than a string? This will mean only the `case 1:` block could ever hope to execute - never the others. Presumably you meant an `if` condition, with a `switch` inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches typically have variable parameters.

Try:

```
if(isset($_GET['price_error']) && $_GET['price_error'] == $x){
    switch($x){ 
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax is actually legal in PHP. Also, `switch` isn't a function, so it doesn't really take parameters... but good point on using an `if` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't defined `$x` variable (I assume that you want it to hold `price_error` id):

```
    $x = isset($_GET['price_error']) ? (int)$_GET['price_error'] : 0;
    switch($x) {
        case 1:
            echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount price cannot be greater than original price</span><br/>';
            break;

        case 2:
            echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount cannot be less than 30% of original price</span><br/>';
            break;

        case 3:
            echo '<span class="error_msg">Discount price and original price cannot be greater than $30000 HKD</span><br/>';
            break;

        default: 
            break;
    }
```